Time complexity of optimal index
Consider a data structure that stores a set of $n$ objects, where each object is a map of arbitrary key-value pair.
The data structure maintains a reverse lookup table, where for each key-value pair, it stores a mapping $(k, v) \to S$, where $S$ is the set of objects containing this key-value pair.
The data structure aims to support the following query: given a list of key-value pairs, return all objects containing all such key-value pairs. For example, for objects x: {a=b, c=d}, y: {a=b, e=f}, the query {a=b} returns both objects while the query {a=b, c=d} returns only the first one.
This is implemented by the following algorithm: for each query key-value pair, retrieve its corresponding object set in the index. Take the set with the fewest objects, and perform linear search to test whether each object matches the rest of the key-value pairs in the query exhaustively, and return the ones that match.
Assuming the simple case where a query of $m$ key-value pairs only matches one object, with no constraints at all about the distribution of other objects, what is the worst case (with the most unfavorable distribution) time complexity of the algorithm? In other words, what is the largest possible size of the smallest matching set in the index?
My intuitive idea considers the following deduction: The whole data structure contains $n$ objects. After reducing the size for $m$ times, we are only left with $1$ object. Each step reduced the set to by $r_1, r_2, \ldots, r_m$ of the remaining, and $\prod_i^m r_i = \frac1n$, so $\min_i r_i \le n^{-m}$, i.e. the optimal index should have no more than $n^{1-\frac1m}$ items (didn't verify this carefully, please point it out if I'm wrong). Nevertheless, this depends on the assumption that the distribution of keys is independent/even across other keys; without this assumption, the value of $r_\text{optimal}$ may differ depending on the preceding query pairs used to reduce the set.
Is there a reasonable upper bound on the size of the optimal index that applies to the general case?
